# Search dictionary values and return List of keys meeting conditions

Tags: c#, arrays, list, linq, dictionary

I've got a problem searching a Dictionary looking like this.

```
Dictionary<string, string[]> dic = new Dictionary<string, string[]>(){
    {"a", new string[](){"a_val","2"}},
    {"b", new string[](){"b_val","1"}},
    {"b", new string[](){"b_val","0"}}
};
```

I need to return a List of the Keys where the value of the stingArray[1] element is bigger than "1" like:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>{
    "a"
};
```

Because I'm not really good at using LINQ, my current solution is iterating over the Dictionary and adding the keys to a new list. But that method looks ugly and I'm trying to find another solution to the problem.

Comment: Wht do the double Asterisks(**) stand for?

Comment: @CasparKleijne Non-applied **bold** formatting .

Comment: I wanted to highlight that index, but that didn't work in code-format.
I'll remove it.

Comment: While you have answers that you have accepted now in future always add the code that you are using. Show us your current method, explain what it is you don't like about it and then ask your question. If nothing else showing us your currently working code is a form of documentation making sure people understand exactly what the solution needs to do.

Comment: You might want to consider a Dictionary<string,Tuple<string,int>> instead of Dictionary<string,string[]>

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Without any error handling:

```
var list = dic.Where(x => int.Parse(x.Value[1]) > 1)
              .Select(x => x.Key)
              .ToList();
```

With the `Where` statement the entries where `Value[1]` is greater 1 will be filtered and with the `Select` statement the key from this entries will be selected. At least the collection will be converted in a `List` with the `ToList` method.

For further information have a look at [101 LINQ Samples in C#](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly and those Samples are great.

Answer (score 3):

Try this(You're dictionary definition has some compiling errors and I made some guess):

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dic = new Dictionary<string, string[]>(){
        {"a", new string[]{"a_val","2"}},
        {"b", new string[]{ "b_val","1"}},
        {"c", new string[]{ "b_val","0"}}};
        string[] expected = dic
            .Where(kv => Convert.ToInt32(kv.Value[1]) > 1)
            .Select(kv => kv.Key).ToArray();
    }
```